# Issue deleting from DGV and Database at same time

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a program using Windows Forms.  It is an inventory program that will allow me to track inventory of various items.  I have a DataGridView displayed on the main page as well as a Remove button.  When I select the row and click the button it will remove the entry from the DataGridView.  When I refresh the entry returns.  I am pretty sure on delete button click I need to establish connection with table...tried a few ways to do it but I seem to be missing something as it just will not work.  Any ideas?  Button2_Click is the delete function.

Main FORM with the DGV:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Main : Form
{        
    public Main()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'userLoginDataSet.WeaponData' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.weaponDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.userLoginDataSet.WeaponData);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AddWeapon aw = new AddWeapon(); // pass this, the main form
        aw.Show();

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Refresh weaponList DataGridView to show latest updates.
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\brmcbrid\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\UserLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        string query = "select * from WeaponData";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        weaponList.DataSource = dt;

    }

    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.weaponList.SelectedRows)
        {
            weaponList.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }







    }      
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should delete the record from the datatable bound to the datagridview ... the datagridview will automatically reflect the change